# Bootstrapping annual and semi annual bond

Tags: fixed-income, interest-rates, bond, bootstrapping, bootstrap

https://www.wallstreetmojo.com/bootstrapping-yield-curve/

**a) This is the standard method for bootstrapping:**

From the 0.5-year maturity the spot rate or the discount rate is 3% and let us assume the discount rate for 1-year maturity be x%, then

100 = 1.75/(1+3%/2)^1 + 101.75/(1+x/2)^2

**b)why this does not work?**

why we divide the coupon by 2 and don't adjust the power as follows? (assume semi annual coupon so 180 days for the 1st cashflow and 360 for the 2nd cashflow):

100 = 1.75/(1+3%)^(180/360) + 101.75/(1+x)^(360/360)

**c) how would the bootstrapping work assuming you have a coupon paid annually and not S/A?**